# Convert InputStreamReader to InputStream

Tags: java, android

How can I convert `InputStreamReader` to `InputStream`? I have an `InputStream` which contains some string and byte data and I want to parse it. So I wrap my `InputStream` to `BufferedReader`. Then I read 3 lines from it. After that I want to get the rest of data(bytes) as is. But if I try to get it nothing happens.
Code snippet:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));

                String endOfData = br.readLine();
                String contentDisposition = br.readLine();
                String contentType = br.readLine();    

                file = new File(filename);
                if(file.exists()) file.delete();
                file.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);                  

                byte[] data = new byte[8192];     
                int len = 0;     

                while (-1 != (len = is.read(data)) )     
                {                
                    fos.write(data, 0, len);  
                    Log.e("len", len+"");
                }      
 fos.flush();
 fos.close();
 is.close();
```

The file is empty. If I don't wrap `InputStream` it works fine, but I need to read 3 lines and remove it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mix text and byte data together, you should use OutputStream.writeUTF to write out those 3 lines, this way one single InputStream will be able to retrieve all the data that you need.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at commons-io's [`ReaderInputStream`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/input/package-summary.html): it is a little heavy handed, but you can wrap the BufferedReader with that and read it as an input stream again.

Answer (score -2):

It's pretty hard to mix byte and character input correctly, especially once you start throwing buffered readers / streams into the mix.  I'd suggest that you either pick one and stick with it (converting your bytes to strings as necessary; care with the encoding!) or wrap the entire thing in a ZipOutputStream so you can have multiple logical "files" with different contents.